# How to find second highest salary in below array list using Java8 streams

Tags: java, java-8

```
class Employee
{
    int id;
     
    String name;
     
    int age;
     
    String gender;
     
    String department;
     
    int yearOfJoining;
     
    double salary;
     
    public Employee(int id, String name, int age, String gender, String department, int yearOfJoining, double salary) 
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.department = department;
        this.yearOfJoining = yearOfJoining;
        this.salary = salary;
    }
     
    public int getId() 
    {
        return id;
    }
     
    public String getName() 
    {
        return name;
    }
     
    public int getAge() 
    {
        return age;
    }
     
    public String getGender() 
    {
        return gender;
    }
     
    public String getDepartment() 
    {
        return department;
    }
     
    public int getYearOfJoining() 
    {
        return yearOfJoining;
    }
     
    public double getSalary() 
    {
        return salary;
    }
     
    @Override
    public String toString() 
    {
        return "Id : "+id
                +", Name : "+name
                +", age : "+age
                +", Gender : "+gender
                +", Department : "+department
                +", Year Of Joining : "+yearOfJoining
                +", Salary : "+salary;
    }
}
```

---

```
List<Employee> employeeList = new ArrayList<Employee>();
         
employeeList.add(new Employee(111, "Jiya Brein", 32, "Female", "HR", 2011, 25000.0));
employeeList.add(new Employee(122, "Paul Niksui", 25, "Male", "Sales And Marketing", 2015, 13500.0));
employeeList.add(new Employee(133, "Martin Theron", 29, "Male", "Infrastructure", 2012, 18000.0));
employeeList.add(new Employee(144, "Murali Gowda", 28, "Male", "Product Development", 2014, 32500.0));
employeeList.add(new Employee(155, "Nima Roy", 27, "Female", "HR", 2013, 22700.0));

Optional<Employee> emp = employeeList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.comparingDouble(Employee::getSalary)));
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? This is not a Q&A site !

Comment: Optional<Employee> emp=
employeeList.stream().collect(Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.comparingDouble(Employee::getSalary)));

Comment: Update the question with what you have tried so far.

Comment: Don't use streams here. Just sort the list using Collections.sort, passing a comparator. Then get the 2nd element from the last. Alternatively you can use a reverse comparator and get the 2nd element.

Comment: @RavindraRanwala This is a Q&A site, this is just not a suitable (well-asked) question.

Answer (score 12):

After sorting the list according to salary in reverse order, you can skip the highest with `skip(1)` then get the first employee after that with `findFirst()` method to find the second highest salary.

Try this:

```
Optional<Employee> emp = employeeList.stream()
        .sorted(Comparator.comparingDouble(Employee::getSalary).reversed()).skip(1).findFirst();

System.out.println(emp.get());
```

Output:

```
Id : 111, Name : Jiya Brein, age : 32, Gender : Female, Department : HR, Year Of Joining : 2011, Salary : 25000.0
```

Comment: Hi @AbinashDash glad it helped :) would you consider accepting/upvoting the answer? Thanks!

Comment: you can do it without sorting: `employeeList.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Employee::getSalary, Function.identity(), (a, b) -> a,
                        () -> new TreeMap<>(Comparator.comparing(Double::doubleValue).reversed())))
                .values().stream().skip(1).findFirst().orElse(null);`

Comment: @HadiJ yeah I tried, definitely works faster but how? I am trying to figure out '...without sorting' part :D thanks for valuable contribution

Comment: @Hülya, As you see I've used `TreeMap` to sort based on _salary_ property.

Answer (score 1):

you need to sort the list, then get 2nd (list index starts from 0).

1.

```java
List<Employee> sortedList = employeeList.stream()
.sorted(Comparator.comparingDouble(Employee::getSalary).reversed()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

2. `sortedList.get(1)`